# rabbitmq con connect after published on iis

Tags: iis, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am hosting asp.net core 2.0 webapi application on iis. but after host my application, rabbitmq host Broker unreachable. i have test this with vs debug mode and it's working fine. so my uri is correct.
here is my code.

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://192.168.100.239:15672/"), "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("vinit");
                    h.Password("vinit");
                    h.Heartbeat(10);
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestQ", e =>
                {
                     e.LoadFrom(provider);
                });
            }));
```

in iis i am getting this error.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostedServiceExecutor[9]
      An error occurred starting the application
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Broker unreachable: vinit@192.168.100.239:15672/) ---> MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException: Broker unreachable: vinit@192.168.100.239:15672/ ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.IO.IOException: connection.start was never received, likely due to a network timeout
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune()
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Open(Boolean insist)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.ProtocolBase.CreateConnection(IConnectionFactory factory, Boolean insist, IFrameHandler frameHandler, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.ConnectionContextFactory.<CreateConnection>d__9.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.ConnectionContextFactory.<CreateConnection>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

is i am missing some thing or need to do any additional setting?

Please suggest me.
Thank you

Comment: 15672 doesn't sound like the right port, remove it and let it use the default. 15672 is the UI/dashboard, not the transport.

Comment: yes, i got it. for transport need to use 5672 port. thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading RabbitMQ Document, i got answer that we can manage port from rabbitmq.config file in our system, and there are different port for transport.

Thank you